# loop using with_sequence over with_subelement in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to loop over a subelement variables using the a loop like with_sequence,

For the moment I have :

```
--- 
- hosts: corosync
  gather_facts: no 

  vars:
    host_list:
     - node_one
     - node_two

    list_services:
     - group: ALPHA
       services:
         - name: DHCP
           directory: /etc/dhcp
         - name: DNS
           directory : /etc/dns
     - group: BETA
       services:
         - name: SSH
           directory: /etc/ssh
         - name: FTP
           directory: /ztc/ftp

 tasks:
 - name: create group-services
   debug:  
      msg: "the service name is {{ item.0.group}}-{{ item.1.name}} , directory is  {{ item.1.directory }}" 

   with_subelements:
    - "{{ list_services }}"
    - services
```

Since I have 2 nodes in my cluster

- node_one
- node_two

I want to deplucate each service like below :

```
{{ item.0.group}}-{{host_id}}-{{ item.1.name}}
```

with `{{ host_id }}` a list that equal `['0','1']` since I have 2 nodes

and the `with_subelement` function loop over the `{{ host_id }}` twice since we have two nodes, what gives :

- ALPHA-0-DHCP
- ALPHA-0-DNS
- ALPHA-1-DHCP
- ALPHA-1-DNS
- BETA-0-SSH
- BETA-0-FTP
- BETA-1-SSH
- BETA-1-FTP

I want to use something like `with_sequence` function beside `with_subelement` like

```
with_sequence: start=0, end={{ groups['host_list']|length}}
```

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 3):

The [`loop` declaration introduced in Ansible 2.5](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#migrating-from-with-x-to-loop) makes it pretty straightforward ー you just need to combine the two patterns replacing [legacy `with_sequence`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-sequence) and [legacy `with_subelements`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements):

```
- name: create group-services
  debug:
    msg: "{{item.1.0.group}}-{{item.0}}-{{item.1.1.name}}"
  loop: "{{ range(0, host_list|length) | product(list_services|subelements('services')) | list }}"
```

Comment: I am using ansible 2.3.1.0 and there is no way to change it :'(

Comment: Or somehow to add the lookup plug-in to my role please

Comment: `range` and `product` filters have been present for long time. For `subelements` go to GitHub and find the filter source in Ansible repository, copy the code as your own custom filter. Replace `loop` in the above task with `with_items`.